# How do I test this writing XML Salesforce documentation in the developer console anonymous window?

Tags: xml, dom, salesforce, apex

I'm trying to learn how to read and write XML using the Document Object Model using this documentation on the Apex developer guide:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to actually generate the XML output for the XmlNode example at the bottom of the document. I see there are printable debug statments but I can't figure out how to see the live results. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean of "live results"?